# Data Fetch from Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, database

I want to fetch data from a collection called 'companies' which has nested documents say 'company_name_1', 'company_name_2', and so on. Each company has another collection 'problems' which has documents named using the Unique IDs produced by Firebase to identify data uniquely. Lastly, each ID branches into three keys problem_link, problem_name, num_ocurr, and status. I have been trying to fetch data for each company and display it in the Accordion of their corresponding company.

This is my config file 'credentials.js':

```
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

    const firebaseConfig = {
        // configuration
    };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app)
    const firestore = getFirestore(app);
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    export {auth, provider, firestore};
```

Then The file where I am facilitating the functionalities of the accordion is in accordian.js

```
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import { firestore } from '../signIn/credentials';

const CompanyAccordion = () => {
  const [companyData, setCompanyData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCompanyData = async () => {
      const snapshot = await getDocs(collection(firestore, 'companies'));
      const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      setCompanyData(data);
    };

    fetchCompanyData();
  }, []);

  const renderProblemTable = (problems) => {
    const sortedProblems = problems.sort((a, b) => a.num_occur - b.num_occur);

    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Problems</th>
            <th>Frequency</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {sortedProblems.map((problem) => (
            <tr key={problem.problem_name}>
              <td>
                <a href={problem.problem_link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                  {problem.problem_name}
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>{problem.num_occur}</td>
              <td>{problem.status ? 'Completed' : 'Incomplete'}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };

  console.log(companyData)

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#141721', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', paddingBottom: '300px' }}>
      {companyData.map((company) => (
        <Accordion className="company" key={company.companyName} sx={{ backgroundColor: '#22262A', maxWidth: '90%', width: '100%', borderRadius: 20 }}>
          <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon sx={{ color: '#fff' }} />} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
            <Typography sx={{ color: '#fff', fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontWeight: '600' }}>
              {company.companyName}
            </Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>{renderProblemTable(company.problems)}</AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CompanyAccordion;
```

However, the code is compiling but I am nothing is being displayed, in fact, the accordion component which was being displayed before the implementation of the data fetching is not being shown.

What's wrong with the code? How do I display the data in a table format for each Company using a different Accordion?